# Google app engine slow TTFB

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, optimization, cdn, google-cdn

I started looking at using Google app engine as CDN, but their TTFB is very poor. Can I do anything to reduce the response time of static content?

[Web Page Performance Test from Dulles](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/110722_E8_1435Z/1/details/)

[Web Page Performance Test from Amsterdam](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/110722_12_1436J/1/details/)

Comment: How are you measuring this? Is your content cached/cacheable, or is it dynamically generated?

Comment: All content stored on olddevils-cdn... (olddevils-cdn.appspot.com) is static content. If you try to open Web Test "Amsterdam" and press the "Re-run the test" button. You find it in the Summary. Our web hotel is a very bad web host and we can get responsider up to 4 seconds, however it is becoming rare. It is fails to find an another web hotel that it supports OpenID in Denmark.

Comment: But you could see that our response times were bad with google app. - What I wanted was to reduce TTFB.

Comment: More precisely, I am looking for a place where our static content can be retrieved with a TTFB of 10 to max 30 ms in Denmark.

Comment: Light travels roughly 9000 km in 30 milliseconds. Since a TCP socket takes two round trips to set up, that means your endpoint has to be within 2250 km of your client, even before switching delays. You're not going to get that sort of latency from anything short of a dedicated CDN.

Comment: The 10 to 30 ms was not mende as minimum and maximum time. But it is very disappointed to have to learn that google app has response times of static content which is far above normal, especially when they normally do, response times of 10 to 60 ms.

Comment: What do you consider 'normal'? And what response times are you seeing, and have you tagged the content as cacheable?

Comment: My experiences in Denmark are TTFB 70 to 150 ms and 10 to 60ms on quality hosts.
And the same with CDN in Eropa and USA.

Comment: Are you thinking of a scalable solutions to cache pages?

Comment: Well, you haven't explained how you're making sure the pages are cached now, so it's hard to say.

Comment: It is not intended that the pages should be up on cdn. - So far.

Comment: ...what? You're not making sense.

Comment: > you tagged the content as cacheable?
- Are you thinking of a scalable solutions to cache pages?
- Well, you haven't explained how you're making sure the pages are cached now, so it's hard to say. <
The answer must be no. I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I have no sense of the scalable options Google Apps provides??

Comment: Your app is served out of a single location at any one time. If you expect very low latency to a given endpoint, your content has to be cacheable (and already cached at the endpoint).

Comment: Can you show me on the way to how it should do it?

Comment: If you are thinking of headers "Cache-Control", it's done.

Comment: @DibloDk let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2049/discussion-between-nick-johnson-and-diblo-dk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google app engine isn't designed to be a CDN, it's a platform for you to build webapps on.  If you're looking for a cheap CDN in app engine, I suggest you use something else.

Comment: Hmm okay I drop Google app engine. Apparently it is not the place to build fast-loading sites.

Comment: @Diblo "Building fast-loading sites" is a totally different thing from looking for a CDN.

Comment: What I wanted was to reduce TTFB. if you try to open Web Test "Amsterdam" and press the "Re-run the test" button you can see that we usually have an approximate time of 950ms and we are located in Copenhagen in Denmark. But our web hotel is a very bad web host and we can get responsider up to 4 seconds, however it is becoming rare. But we have no money to move on the expensive host and it is fails to find an another web hotel that it supports OpenID in Denmark.

Comment: Sorry. You must go to the Summary in order to find the "Re-run the test" button

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would like to add here is: Not all CDNs are designed to improve TTFB. In fact, 9 out of 10 will contribute to the delay - not help solve the issue.

To affect TTFB you need to kick off browser parsing as fast as possible. To do that, you have to reduce HTML processing time - which is your main delay factor.

I recently wrote a post about it, you may find it useful: 
http://www.incapsula.com/the-incapsula-blog/item/809-using-cdn-to-improve-seo-and-ttfb

Comment: `To affect TTFB you need to kick off browser parsing as fast as possible` <- that doesn't make any sense, or I'm misreading it. I understand that to mean "To affect TTFB the browser needs to parse the bytes it has received as fast as possible" - How does processing bytes already received affect when the first byte *was* already received?

Comment: You misunderstanding it. TTFB, in SEO context, refers not to first 200OK received but to the time it takes to get the .html object. Read this https://plus.google.com/+IlyaGrigorik/posts/GTWYbYWP6xP again. Ilya is a performance engineer for Google and he clearly says: "The problem is that it's not only the time that matters, but also what's in those first few bytes..." (read more inside).